# Proxy server for Gatling

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, performance-testing, http-proxy, gatling

Recently I installed **Gatling** for performance testing on Ubuntu 14.04. And to run the recorder I needed to configure a proxy server in my browser. I tried to change proxy settings in Google chrome, but I don`t have rights. So I tried to do it using network settings in Ubuntu (Network -> Network proxy). But when I open a website which I need to test, nothing happens in the recorder. 
So I do not really know is there a problem with the proxy server or **Gatling** itself? And how to check if the proxy server is configured correctly?
I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try to record using Gatling and after recording you can see the scala script in the default folder where you installed Gatling.

Comment: you can store the request from network tab(F12 - developer tools) by capturing network logs. copy all as HAR and then use HAR converter in Gatling recorder to create your scala file.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit too late, but I had a similar problem today. Was able to solve only by setting global IP address like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Nor localhost nor 127.0.0.1 worked for me Chrome. After that I was able to notice http requests in Recorder inside `Executed Events`

Hopefully it could help somebody else

Edit : this is how setting looks like in Chrome, taking into account you have specified in Recorder Listening port to be 8000 also:
[image]

Comment: I've specified the global address inside the Chrome Advanced settings (You could find the path to settings here : [link](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows)). Through, compared to this page: uncheck both checkboxes and Select `Proxy Servre Use a proxy server for you LAN...`